# removing rows and columns of sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix (F). I want to be able to do some filtering on it to reduce it a little more. I want to remove all rows/columns that meet the following criteria.

1. Delete rows in which sum of row is < 50
2. Delete columns in which sum of columns < 150

I tried the code below which I thought would work with indexing but I get a dimensionality error:

```
F = F[F.sum(axis=1)>=50][F.sum(axis=0)>=150]
```

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e13bff9f8066> in <module>()
----> 1 F = F[F.sum(axis=1)>=50][F.sum(axis=0)>=150]
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py in __getitem__(self, index)
    191 
    192         try:
--> 193             out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
    194         finally:
    195             self._getitem = False

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

I am still learning Python so appreciate any help with an explanation!

Comment: When debugging code like this, test individual steps.  e.g. `F.sum(axis-1)`, the first indexing, etc.  And yes, `scipy.sparse` matrices have their own quirks, and can't be handled exactly the same as normal `numpy` arrays.  At least during testing, freely use `F.A` to examine and experiement with the dense equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Sparse array `.sum()` returns a `np.matrix` instead of an ndarray and it behaves weird with indexing (it's 2d instead of the 1d array you were probably expecting).

Turn it into an array and combine the indexing and it works fine:

`F = F[(F.sum(axis=1)>=50).A.flatten(), (F.sum(axis=0)>=150).A.flatten()]`.

Comment: A `np.matrix` has a `A1` property to return `A.flatten()`.

Comment: For some reason, I am getting another error when applying the above:   
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape